# Braille Recognition from an image using OpenCV/C++

Tags: c++, ios, opencv, image-processing, braille

I am aiming to develop an iOS app that captures an image > extracts Braille dots represented in a specific color (Blue) > translates Braille letters into text using image processing techniques.

My approach was to use OpenCV/C++ to have the image be processed to extract the blue colored dots as shown in [this photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L62Ty.png) into [this photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/91isf.jpg)

The next step is to recognize Braille in the image to translate it into text, one solution was to put a grid on the image to find the intersection points pixel color value then classify them into (1 if white , 0 if black) as represented in [this photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HajTK.jpg)

The problem with the proposed solution was:

1. how to position the grid rows/columns at the wanted positions?
2. how to get the coordinates and value(0 or 1)of the intersection points?

If you have any suggestion/solution about the proposed solution or any other solution please share them It would be appreciated since I don't have an experience in OpenCV/C++ field.

*note that python solutions cannot be used in iOS (as far as I know).

I attached my code for reference

```
 + (UIImage *)detectRedShapesInImage:(UIImage *)image{
cv::Mat mat;
UIImageToMat(image, mat);
cv::medianBlur(mat, mat, 3);

// Convert input image to HSV
cv::Mat hsv_image;
cv::cvtColor(mat, hsv_image, cv::COLOR_BGR2HSV);

// Threshold the HSV image, keep only the red (replaced it with blue) pixels
cv::Mat lower_red_hue_range;
cv::Mat upper_red_hue_range;
cv::inRange(hsv_image, cv::Scalar(0, 100, 100), cv::Scalar(10, 255, 255), lower_red_hue_range);
cv::inRange(hsv_image, cv::Scalar(160, 100, 100), cv::Scalar(179, 255, 255), upper_red_hue_range);

// Combine the above two images
cv::Mat red_hue_image;
cv::addWeighted(lower_red_hue_range, 1.0, upper_red_hue_range, 1.0, 0.0, red_hue_image);
cv::GaussianBlur(red_hue_image, red_hue_image, cv::Size(9, 9), 2, 2);


// detect circules, for now it doesnot take all circles
std::vector<cv::Vec4f> circles;
cv::HoughCircles(red_hue_image, circles, cv::HOUGH_GRADIENT, 1.0, 20,  150, 40, 0, 0);

// Loop over all detected circles and outline them on the original image
if(circles.size() == 0) std::exit(-1);
for(size_t current_circle = 0; current_circle < circles.size(); ++current_circle) {
    cv::Point center(std::round(circles[current_circle][0]), std::round(circles[current_circle][1]));
    int radius = std::round(circles[current_circle][2]);
    
    cv::circle(red_hue_image, center, radius, cv::Scalar(0, 255, 0), 5);
    
}


UIImage *maskedShapesImg = MatToUIImage(red_hue_image);

return maskedShapesImg;}
```

Comment: Have you looked into the literature for solutions? This is a problem that surely has been solved, you shouldn’t reinvent the wheel.

Comment: I did my search before posting this and didn't find what I needed, but I may have missed some, if you have something that could help please don't hesitate to share them! and thank you @CrisLuengo

Answer (score 1):

**Hints:**

Assuming that the text is fairly horizontal and the spacing between lines is sufficient:

- get the centers of the dots;
- find the shortest horizontal and vertical distances between dots; these give you the horizontal and vertical pitch;
- cluster the dots that are no more than one horizontal or two vertical pitches apart (with a safety margin); a cluster should correspond to a single character;
- find the top-left corner of the characters;
- find the median horizontal and vertical distance between the characters;
- from this information (dot and character spacing), map the dots to the grid by predicting the grid nodes and using the nearest-neighbor rule.

This work is made a little tricky by the fact that not all character occupy the two columns and three rows of dots.

Comment: Thank u for your hints @Yves Daoust ! I tried a solution that followed the same logic and it worked but I had the same problem that you have mentioned ( characters which are represented using one column are not detected correctly), is there a way that you suggest to solve this problem ?

Comment: @MadawiAh: estimate the spacing between the two-column characters. This should allow you to make the correct decision in ambiguous cases. [Note that if the spacing is not constant, or if the character is isolated, there is nothing you can do, reading is forever ambiguous.]